# PopupWindow throws BadTokenException

Tags: android

If I add the `showPopupWindow();` in the `oCreate()` directly, it will give an error：

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

like this following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    showPopupWindow();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             showPopupWindow();
        }
    });
}

private void showPopupWindow() {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("This is a Text");
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#33000000"));
    //悬浮窗体
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(textView,-2,-2);
    //设置View
    popupWindow.setContentView(textView);
    //设置宽高
    //必须设置背景
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
    //父窗体，Gravity，位置（x距离左边的距离，y距离上边的距离）
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.rl_main), Gravity.LEFT + Gravity.TOP, 60, 60);

}
```

but if I add it into `onClick`, it will be ok, like following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopupWindow();
        }
    });
}

private void showPopupWindow() {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("This is a Text");
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#33000000"));
    //悬浮窗体
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(textView,-2,-2);
    //设置View
    popupWindow.setContentView(textView);
    //设置宽高
    //必须设置背景
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
    //父窗体，Gravity，位置（x距离左边的距离，y距离上边的距离）
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.rl_main), Gravity.LEFT + Gravity.TOP, 60, 60);

}
```

Please help me in understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's too early to show popup window in `onCreate()` method because till that time, activity might not have completed the required life cycle. You need to differ your solution by implementing a delay of fraction of seconds.

Comment: I will have a try follow your advice

Comment: I follow your advice ,but it failed to me ,I add it into onCreate()      try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        showPopupWindow();`

Answer (score 0):

Use **Handler** instead of `Thread.sleep()`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

then after setContentView();

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{   
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        showPopupWindow();
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: uhm sorry, try it after setContentView.